# ¿Cómo fuerzo unos commits locales en un repositorio que tiene otros commits posteriores?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Tengo un repositorio remoto en el cual hay 4 commits. En mi repositorio local tenía la última versión del remoto, pero decidí regresar al commit 2 a partir del comando:

```
git checkout eb9b03c
```

Para que mi head apunte al 2.º commit.

A continuación, no generé ninguna nueva rama, sino que trabajé sobre este commit y generé después un nuevo commit con los cambios realizados. Entonces, en mi repositorio local tengo 3 commits, mientras en el remoto tengo 4.

Al realizar un

```
git push origin main
```

Me genera el siguiente error:

```
To https://github.com/alondraSanchezM/calamus.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/alondraSanchezM/calamus.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes 
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Supongo que realizando un `git pull` ya me dejaría realizar el push, pero quiero eliminar los dos commits que están en el remoto y mantener mi último commit el repositorio local como el último commit en el remoto también.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que eso hará que tu remoto pierda información (lo suyo sería que bajes lo último e integres los nuevos cambios)

Comment: Si, no importa que el remoto pierda los 2 ultimos commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que has hecho es lo que se conoce como "reescribir la historia" algo que suele traer problemas cuando se trabaja con git.. Pero algo muy útil en general.

Si consideramos tu caso antes de que hicieras los checkouts. Hay dos opciones a seguir

Una es hacer un `git revert` de los dos commits. Lo cual genera dos nuevos commits deshaciendo los cambios anteriores.

Es el método mas simple pero deja "sucio" el log, ya que verás los commits con los cambios y los 2 commits con el revert.

La otra es la que has hecho, que es apuntar tu HEAD dos commits atrás y trabajar desde ahí como si nada.

El problema es que al querer pasarlo al remote estás intentando decirle al remote algo que no le cuadra. Ya que la historia solo está sobreescrita para ti.

Si haces un merge como comentas, te encontrarás con varios conflictos que tendrás que resolver. Pero en el resultado final seguirás viendo los 2 commits qué habías intentado borrar.

En este caso, si quieres remplazar lo que el remoto tiene deberás hacer lo que se conoce como un "force push" `git push origin HEAD --force`

Pero **cuidado!** el force push es muy útil para estos casos pero no es una herramienta de la que deberías abusar. si ese remoto lo usan otros usuarios, desde el momento en el que hagas el force push todo el mundo tendrá problemas para subir sus cambios, porque sus historias no corresponden con la nueva historia que tu has creado.

Si ese es el caso, lo mas recomendable es hacer un `git reset --soft` de tus cambios. Eso quitará los commits pero dejará los cambios en tu árbol de trabajo. Luego haces un `git stash` (guardas el trabajo en un sitio aparte.

Haces un pull para traer la historia tal y como estaba, haces el `git revert` y añades tus cambios con `git stash pop`.
De esa forma no sobreescribes la historia pero reviertes esos commits que no quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás segura de que no quieres los dos commits posteriores que están en el repositorio pero no en local, simplemente haz:

```
git push -f origin <tu_rama>
```

Esto forzará (de ahí el `-f`, de **f**orce) que el repositorio acoja (más bien okupe) lo que tienes en local.

Si además quieres "eliminar" los commits que había en remoto y no en local, puedes hacer:

```
git push -f origin <último_commit_válido>:<tu_rama>
```

En tu caso, `git push -f origin eb9b03c:tu_rama`. Explico con más detalle en [Git - Undo pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36177806/1983854).